# How to Make Dynamic Web Search Bar Using HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a dynamic search bar that can search in places like Google, Bing, Yahoo, etc.

I have already tried the code from this tutorial: https://youtu.be/AlNDsaZLBfQ, but Firefox blocks that type of scripts so I decided to do an alternative, Javascript.

This is where I've gotten so far:

```html
<input id="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="search the web.."><button id="go">Go</button>
<form id="options" action=""></form>
<script>
const seData = [

  {
    name: "Google",
    url: "https://www.google.com/search?&q=%s"
    //"%s" is substituted with the search terms 
  },
  {
    name: "Yahoo",
    url: "https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=%s&fr=opensearch"
  },
  {
    name: "Bing",
    url: "https://www.bing.com/search?q=%s"
  }
];
function optionControls(seData) {
return `
<label>${seData.name}<input type="radio" id="${seData.name}Checkbox" name="searchEngine"></label>
`
}
document.getElementById("options").innerHTML = 
`${seData.map(optionControls).join('')}`



</script>
```

What I want is a page with an input box, radio buttons, and a submit button which, when clicked, will redirect the user to the selected search engine results page.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about what you want this page to do? Are you simply looking to create a page with an input box, radio buttons, and a submit button which, when clicked, will redirect the user to the selected search engine results page?

Comment: Exactly correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to fix is your radio buttons, the need to have a common name.

Next put all form elements in the form and on form submit, grab the details an redirect

```js
const seData = [

  {
    name: "Google",
    url: "https://www.google.com/search?&q=%s"
    //"%s" is substituted with the search terms 
  },
  {
    name: "Yahoo",
    url: "https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=%s&fr=opensearch"
  },
  {
    name: "Bing",
    url: "https://www.bing.com/search?q=%s"
  }
];
function optionControls(seData) {
 //Note: name must be common to the radio buttons in a set. Use value to store the "name"
return `
<label>${seData.name}<input type="radio" id="${seData.name}Checkbox" value="${seData.name}" name="searchEngine"></label>
`
}
document.getElementById("options").innerHTML += 
`${seData.map(optionControls).join('')}`


//Event handler for form submit
document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  //Get the selected radio button value
  var eng = this.querySelector("[name=searchEngine]:checked").value;
  //Get the selected data
  eng = seData.filter(se => se.name === eng)[0];
  //UPdate the url details and redirect
  window.location.href = eng.url.replace("%s", document.getElementById("searchBar").value);
  //Stop the form from actually submitting
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
})
```

```html
<!-- I"ve put everything in the form -->
<form id="searchForm" method="GET" action="">
<input id="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="search the web.."><button id="go">Go</button>
<!-- New div to hold the radio buttons -->
<div id="options"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: The code almost works, but firefox is blocking the script:
https://i.imgur.com/ewByHOj.png

Comment: That error `load denied by X-frame-Options` is because google (not fire fox) blocks it's site from being loaded in `iFrames` which is part of StackSnippets. If you host this code outside of an `iFrame` it will be fine. You can't over ride the hots X-frame-Options.